# Point of Sale Application Architecture

Tags: .net, architecture, prism, point-of-sale

I have been asked to build a POS Application for a Restaurant. I have experience creating POS application in VB6.0 and have always wanted to create one with UX. I am looking to create one with WPF as front end. I pretty much have the process picture in mind and also screens.

Said so much, I am not sure how to Architecture one.

Few Major questions that come to my mind are :

Should I use Composite Application Guidance for WPF - Prism. If the answer is yes will performance reduce as in POS Application, time can be critical, customers want prompt service.

I am thinking Dependency Injection should be used for better maintenance.

using ADO.NET Entity Framework- LinQ to SQL

I want to grow this application later to include Inventory Management and Data Mining, Management reports.

will use POS for .NET

Hope I will be able to get this all cleared up this weekend.

Please Advise.

Thank you,

Mar

Edit:
I am still leaving it open will like to get more views/ advises.

Comment: Any update @TheMar....It would be a great help if you provide some R&D abstract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of general questions there, I'll try to touch a little on everything.

In general you should check out the [Application Architecture Guide](http://www.codeplex.com/AppArchGuide).  It's a very good, general primer on architecting all sorts of .NET applications.

I don't think you are going to have any problem with [Prisim](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF).  Take specific note of the [MVVM Pattern](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650).  On the "performance" issue, I think what you are really talking about is "responsiveness".  So a POS allplication needs to be very responsive to the user.  Using WVVM, you can get very good responsiveness in your application.

Personally, I would stay away from this version of Entity Framework (although [next version is looking good](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/05/18/sneak-preview-entity-framework-4-0-testability-improvements.aspx)).  I think LinqToSQL is fine (afterall, SO uses it :)  Look at [NHibernate for .NET](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) if you want ORM.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you JP. Yes I was talking about responsiveness when using frameworks like Prism. After going through lot of web material NHibernate for .NET seems to be too big for this project making me favor towards LinQ to SQL. going through Application Architecture Guide as of now.